# how to change kernel name

Tags: kernel

How do I change kernel name to any name like `Linux 3.13.0-53-generic` to any name and version `ABC 3.12.0.53 generic` So that If i logged out from any site like Face-book it sends me back via email of that recent login from Firefox on OS `ABC 3.13.0-53-generic` With IP.

How can it be done?

Comment: Why don't you just use a proxy to connect using another browser if you want to test this?  (recompiling your own kernel is the other option and a lot of work)  What are you trying to accomplish here???

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to achieve can be done by just changing your web browser's User-Agent. That is how Facebook and other sites know about your OS and it's version.

**Addon for Firefox**: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

**Extension for Chrome/Chromium**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg/related

### Example

Change the following User-Agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64 3.13.0-53-generic; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
```

to

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; ABC x86_64 3.13.0-53-generic; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
```